# What does it mean '400 upvotes for silver badge in certain tag'?

Tags: discussion, reputation, badges, tag-badges

I thought that it meant that I should get 400 upvotes (which equals to 4000 points) only for my answers to questions which weren't marked as community wiki.

But I've just seen [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/276101/polygenelubricants) with reputation a little bigger than 4000, who has a silver badge in the [java](/questions/tagged/java) tag. He couldn't have earned the 4k for the answers only (I didn't count, but he earned at least 500 points for asking questions and at least 300 for answers to questions without the Java tag).

So, how are these 400 upvotes calculated?

Comment: According to this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=java&sort=stats&pagesize=10 that user has had 470 votes in the Java tag in the last 30 days.

Comment: 471 now! polygene is a machine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The badge undoubtedly counts upvotes received above and beyond the rep cap. Thus, rep cannot be used as reliable gauge to determine a person's eligibility for silver tag badges.

(I was apparently wrong in the original about CW posts and questions. The badge does explicitly state that it is for answers only.)

Comment: Upvotes on CW posts *aren't* counted in the total, and neither are question upvotes.

Comment: The important point here is beyond the repcap votes on answers *do* count. 189 answers in 24 days implies 8ish answers a day. If he's averaging +3 on them he's already over the rep cap...

Answer (score 4):

The user could have lost reputation, either by being downvoted, or spending it on bounties.

Comment: From the rep graph, he spent 200 on a bounty.